# ¿Por qué no me imprime el valor solicitado en main cuando llamo un método de una clase B, cuyo método requiere información de una clase A?

Tags: java, clase, objeto

Muy buenas, es que necesito ayuda con una problema que tengo:

Resulta ser que yo quiero desde la clase main llamar a un método que pertenezca a una clase B, dicho método mostrará información en pantalla, sin embargo, dicha información a mostrar está almacenada en una clase A. Por lo tanto, para que el método de la clase B pueda mostrar dicha información, este necesita acceder a la clase A que contiene esa información. Eso sí, primero se creo la información de la clase A.

Hasta aquí, yo entiendo que eso "debería" funciona, pero no es así: Cuando ejecuto el programa, en vez de mostrarme el valor solicitado, me tira un simple 0.

Aquí está el main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    A objectoA = new A(); //Objecto de la clase A.
    B objectoB = new B(); //Objecto de la clase B.

    objectoA.agregarPersonas();        
    objectoB.mostrarInfo();
} //Fin del main.
```

Aquí estaría la clase A:

```
//Aquí está mi declaración y longitudad de mi arreglo.    

public int personas[] = new int[2];        

public void agregarPersonas(){

    //Aquí es donde se inicializa los dos valores al arreglo.

    personas[0] = 24;
    personas[1] = 26;

} //Fin del metodo.
```

Y aquí está la clase B:

```
A objectoA = new A(); //Objecto de la clase A para acceder a los datos.

public void mostrarInfo(){

    System.out.println(objectoA.personas[0]);

} //End of method.
```

A lo que doy a entender, el main primero ejecuta el método A y crea la información, una vez eso, baja a la siguiente linea y ejecuta el método de la clase B, que llama a la información creada en la clase A para mostrar ese valor, pero solo me tira un 0.

Espero que me esté dando a explicar bien. Apreciaría mucho la ayuda.

¡Gracias!

Comment: Si nos dices qué son tus clases  `A`  y  `B` en la realidad quizá podríamos ayudarte mejor. Las respuestas dadas son válidas, pero yo me pregunto si no estamos más bien ante un problema que se puede resolver mediante herencia de clases. Si me dices que tu clase `A` es para guardar personas y tu clase `B` es para guardar médicos o abogados o policías o agentes tributarios es claro que es mejor que eches mano de la herencia. De la herencia de clases digo, no de la herencia de tu familia.

Comment: ¡Claro! Es que yo necesito realizar un proyecto para un curso de programación, y se me ocurrió que en el programa uno pueda hacer un "log in" en el sistema. Entonces, yo creé una clase llamada "Trabajadores", quien tiene un método para agregar un trabajador al sistema en sí. El trabajador va a crear su propio "username" y "password". Entonces, mi primera idea fue crear una clase "Log in" que tuviera el método para validar el acceso. Sin embargo, no me funcionó, por lo que el método lo hice en la clase trabajadores, pero la idea era tener todo más organizado. Es que ocupo usar 8 clases,

Comment: Creo que estás un poco confundido en esto: _«yo creé una clase llamada "Trabajadores", quien tiene un método para agregar un trabajador al sistema en sí. El trabajador va a crear su propio "username" y "password"»_ La clase `Trabajador` tiene ya su método para crear instancias, ese método es el constructor de la clase, si agregaste otro método más y metiste en él código que pertenece a la lógica del programa, mucho me temo que estés mezclando conceptos y empezando a escribir código spaghetti.

Comment: Mmmm... Sí te entiendo, pero es que en la clase Trabajadores yo creé un arreglo de objectos llamado "trabajadores[]" de longitud 2 que utilizaría al constructor y los atributos de la clase Trabajadores (nombre, apellidos, edad) para agregar un valor a este arreglo. Eso sí, yo no quiero hacerlo manual, entonces yo cree un método en la clase Trabajadores llamado "agregarTrabajador()" que le permite al usuario mediante el scanner agregar un nuevo trabajador al array creado llamando dicho método desde el main con un menu.

Comment: Vas mal haciendo eso. Para empezar, las clases tienen que llamarse en singular, no en plural (eso ya es motivo de confusiones). La clase debe llamarse **`Trabajador`** y debes tener bien claro que esa clase sirve para crear **objetos del tipo `Trabajador`**. Si por algún motivo en tu programa se requiere manejar listas de trabajadores, entonces quizá haya que crear una clase que se llame `ListaTrabajadores`, donde habría un miembro que almacene listas de objetos de tipo `Trabajador`. No sé si me entiendes, la POO debe reflejar la realidad, ¿acaso **todo** trabajador maneja una lista?

Comment: Sí, le entiendo ahí. Entonces, sería mejor crear una clase Trabajador, y una clase que básicamente contenga una lista de los trabajadores que se agregarán mediante la clase Trabajador. Así tendríamos: Trabajador y ListaTrabajadores. Trabajador simplemente sería una plantilla para agregar un trabajador que se almacenará en ListaTrabajadores. Hasta momento, esto es lo que entiendo. O sea, ¿el método para agregar un trabajador iría en la clase ListaTrabajadores? ¿O iría en Trabajadores? Porque digamos, si yo quiero leer un trabajador de la lista, el método iría en ListaTrabajadores, ¿sería así?

Comment: Correcto. En la POO te ayudará pensar cada clase como un *molde*, donde se fabrican objetos de un tipo determinado. El problema es que si en la clase `Trabajador` tú metes una lista de trabajadores o métodos que manejen listas de trabajadores, ya esa clase no responde a la realidad, porque **no todo trabajador necesitará manejar una lista**, o dicho de otro modo, esa lista pertenece a otra cosa que sería ya parte de la lógica del programa, no del modelo de datos en sí. En la clase `Trabajador` debe ir **solamente** los atributos que son propios de **todo trabajador** en cualquier contexto.

Comment: ¡Ohhh! ¡Excelente, excelente! Más bien se lo agradezco mucho y la paciencia que ha tenido con migo. La idea mía es que haya un gerente que pueda agregar, modificar, o leer un trabajador de dicha lista. Sin embargo, un trabajador va a poder leer la información básica de un compañero, nada más. De aquí es dónde me sirve todo esto.

Comment: Pues lo mismo, si hay jerarquía entre los empleados, quizá haga falta extender el modelo de datos, creando una clase `Gerente`, otra clase `Supervisor`, otra clase `Operario`  ... y todas ellas extenderían de una clase *padre*  que representaría a los empleados en general, que sería la clase `Empleado` o la misma clase `Trabajador`. Por ejemplo, la clase `Gerente` tendría **solamente** aquellos atributos que son **propios de los gerentes y de nadie más**  y en ese clase puedes dar acceso a ciertos métodos que otras clases no tendrían. Pensarás que fragmentar así es complicar, pero no.

Comment: Entiendo, entiendo, sí, nada más sería de sentarme un rato y organizar ideas. 

Perfecto, más bien muchísimas gracias otra vez por la gran ayuda que me ha dado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero que nada, necesitas rever un par de cosas (puedes leer mas detalles [aquí](http://www.codexion.com/tutorialesjava/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html)).

> El operador **new** instancia una clase reservando memoria para un
>   objeto **nuevo** y devolviendo una referencia a esa memoria

Con esto lo que te quiero decir es que, cada vez que tu haces:

```
A objectoA = new A();  // Crea un objeto nuevo
B objectoB = new B();  // Crea un objeto nuevo
```

Entonces cuando tu haces `new A()` dentro de la clase B, creas un **nuevo** objeto A, totalmente vació, no con los datos antes inicializados en el main.

---

Aclaro esto, lo que deberías hacer si quieres retornar en la clase B, los datos de una clase determina (por ejemplo la clase A), se la tienes que enviar en el argumento del constructor.

```
 public B(A objetoEnviadoPorParametro) {
        objectoA  = objetoEnviadoPorParametro; // Aquí asignas el A que le envías en el constructor, a la propiedad de tu objeto.
    }
```

Luego debes crear B y enviarle el objetoA(con los datos), de la siguiente forma:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   A objectoA = new A();
   //Agregas los valores al objetoA para luego poder mostrarlos
   objectoA.agregarPersonas();
   B objectoB = new B(objectoA); 
   //Ahora muestras la información del objetoA que le enviaste cuando creaste la instancia de B
   objectoB.mostrarInfo();
}
```

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias! Sí voy a pegarme esa leída ahí. He estado batallando bastantillo para poder realizar esto.

Answer (score 1):

Aquí un ejemplo de como llegar a imprimir la información que requieres:

Clase A:

```
public class A {
    // Aquí está mi declaración y longitud de mi arreglo.
    public int personas[] = new int[2];

    public int[] agregarPersonas() {
        // Aquí es donde se inicializa los dos valores al arreglo.
        personas[0] = 24;
        personas[1] = 26;
        return personas;
    } // Fin del metodo.
}
```

Clase B:

```
public class B {
    A objectoA = new A(); // Objecto de la clase A para acceder a los datos.

    public void mostrarInfo() {
        objectoA.agregarPersonas();
        
        // IMPRIME LOS DOS ELEMENTOS INICIALIZADOS EN LA CLASE A
        for(int elemento :  objectoA.agregarPersonas()){
            System.out.println(elemento);
        }
    } // End of method.
}
```

Y finalmente la clase main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // A objectoA = new A(); //Objecto de la clase A.
        B objectoB = new B(); //Objecto de la clase B.

        //objectoA.agregarPersonas();// Este método no es necesario debido a que ya fue llamado en la clase B        
        objectoB.mostrarInfo();
    } //Fin del main.
}
```

Al momento de Imprimir el array en el main, te devuelve lo siguiente:

> 24
>
> 26

En donde estos elementos son los dos inicializados en la clase A.

Comment: Sí me funcionó, pero ahora se me generó una duda: 

Cada vez que yo ejecute este "objectoB.mostrarInfo();" ¿me volvería a crear el arreglo una y otra vez?

Digamos que yo desearía ejecutar dicho método varias veces, sin embargo, no quiero que me haga el arreglo una y otra vez al ejecutarlo. 

Otra pregunta rápida, ¿este "return personas;" de qué me serviría? 

¡Muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Si tu llamas al método mostrarInfo(), siempre se va a imprimir el array con los elementos (24,25), debido a que en dicho método se llama a agregarPersonas() en el cual inicializas el valor del array. Por otra parte el "return personas" sirve para que el array esté disponible al llamar la función mostrarInfo(), si quisieras cambiar el comportamiento de éste método , se debería crear parámetros a dicho método dependiendo de lo que desees mostrar al llamar al método. Deberías definir que deseas obtener al llamar al método mostrarInfo() cada vez que lo necesites, para avanzar con la respuesta